# Error in IE 8 of javascript script 'Object doesn't support this property or method'

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question about the javascript. I write a function in the javascript and I write the function in .html file.

However, when I click the button, it shows the 'Object doesn't support this property or method' error in IE 8.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

```
function colour (colour) {
    var selectTxt =    
       window.getSelection() ||
       document.getSelection() ||
       (document.selection ? document.selection.createRange().text : ''),
       targetHTML = document.getElementById('text'); // text is a id in HTML
       targetHTML.innerHTML =
         targetHTML.innerHTML.replace(
                  RegExp(selectTxt),
                  '<span class="' + colour + '">'+selectTxt+'</span>');
}

// HTML
<input type="button" onclick="colour('green')" value="Green"/>
<p id='text'>I live in ABC and I am working in ABC company.</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're executing the methods before checking if they exist, so when such method is not supported (e.g. window.getSelection) you'll indeed get error.

Add such function to your code:

```
function GetSelectedText() {
    if (window.getSelection)
        return window.getSelection();
    if (document.getSelection)
        return document.getSelection();
    if (document.selection)
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    return "";
}
```

Then simply have:

```
var selectTxt =  GetSelectedText();
```

Comment: Something John should read: [Introduction to Range](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html)